# vue does not display .svg file in local env

Tags: laravel, vue.js, svg, assets

I am making some project with Laravel, Vue2 now.
I deployed my project onto the test server, there .svg files display, but in my local environment they don't display.
I use `:src="asset('images/ico_arrow_left1.svg')"` in vue component.
My images and svg files are all in root/public/images folder.

For example; I wrote the following code to display svg in vue component.

```
<a @click="previousDay"><img class="ico_ico_arrow" :src="asset('images/ico_arrow_left1.svg')"></a>
```

The codes are sampe in test server and local.
show in test server, but not show in local, why?

Answer (score 0):

If you want import a file from public folder you should check the [documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#static-assets-handling). You should use require when you import dynamic asset.  Like this:

```
<img class="ico_ico_arrow" :src="require('images/ico_arrow_left1.svg')"/>
```

Comment: But, in test server, svg displays. @Furkan Karakuze.

Comment: Because in your server files are served as something like 'https://example.com/images/image.svg'  from build while in local you need to define that  you need image from your public folder so you use require to import your image

Answer (score 0):

The `asset()` helper function is only for the Laravel Blade template. you can't use it inside of a regular Vue application.

In Vue, you should use `require()`in order to solve this problem.